# What are the limit points of $\sin(2n \pi/3)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to find the limit points of $a_n = \sin(2n \pi/3)$. So far I've identified the subsequences $a_{3n} = 0$ and $a_{1} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $a_2 = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ so are the limit points $\left\{0, \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right\}$? How do I show there aren't more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already shown the sequence is periodic and only takes three values. If you want to be pedantic, you can let $x\in\Bbb R$ be another value, and but then $|x-a_n|\ge m = \min_{1\le k\le 3}|x-a_k|$, so with $\epsilon = m/2$ you see that you cannot have any sequence of $a_n$s so that you get within $\epsilon$ of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

A limit point is a point (number) for which there is a subsequence that converges to that point. Now any subsequence must have either infinitely many $0$'s or infinitely many $\dfrac {\sqrt 3} 2$'s or infinitely many $-\dfrac {\sqrt 3} 2$'s, so the limit can ONLY be one of these three numbers.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong direction of implication. What I said is enough; if a subsequence converges to $z$ and it has a sub-subsequence that is CONSTANT, then $z$ must be that constant.